# Using Airflow connection from environment instead of db

Tags: python, https, airflow

On a windows machine in order for the get_conn() to work in airflow we need to prefix it with AIRFLOW_CONN and the conn_id.

This will use the following from base_hook
_get_connection_from_env

I usually do this for MSSQL connections where the trusted authentication is in the connection string.

Now I need to do it with HTTP hook, but I'm not sure how to include the login and password information to the environment variable value. I've tried using the ampersand character to separate Login and Password but this gets pushed into the extra attribute of the conn;

INFO - Using connection to: id: https_euromonitor. Host: api.site.com, Port: None, Schema: , Login: None, Password: None, extra: {'Login': 'login', 'Password': 'password'}

How to specify in the environement variable AIRFLOW_CONN_API_SITE the login and password?

Answer (score 0):

http://username:password@example.com is the value to inject into the environment variable.